# How to fix Android Studio 2022.1.1 Build Error?

Tags: android, build

I have upgraded AS to ElectricEel 2022.1.1. When I try to build an old project, I get the following error message:

**"com/android/tools/idea/gradle/run/OutputBuildAction has been compiled by a more recent version
of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0"**

I've searched SO and elsewhere for this error but no joy. What causes this and how do I fix it?

Comment: try this: Select your project -> click on properties -> Select JAVA Build PATH -> change JRE to the more recent version -> apply

Comment: (Dolphin 2021.3.1 is not the latest version.)

Comment: I don't see "properties",or Select "JAVA Build Path"

Answer (score 0):

The problrm is in Java Runtime JRE.
Gradle was compiled for JRE 11. Class file version 55.0 is from Java 11.
And in you Android Studio you point to Java 8.
In Android Studio go to:
File -> Settings (Preferences) -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JDK -> Select JDK 11
Or embeded in studio JDK